# How to convert an anonymous function to a method value?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

With this code

```
val foo = List('a', 'b', 'c')
aString.forall(foo.contains(_))
```

IntelliJ highlights foo.contains(_) and suggests "Anonymous function convertible to method value". I have researched eta expansion, but am unable to see how I could improve this particular piece of code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it's saying that you could simply have

```
val foo = List('a', 'b', 'c')
aString.forall(foo.contains)
```

Note that we're not explicitly converting the `foo.contains` method here to an anonymous function.